# Is $+15/3$ a natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, arithmetic

I know that $15/3=5$, and $5$ is a natural number, but is $15/3$ a natural number?

Comment: Yes, it is. Like asking whether $\;i\cdot i=-1\;$ is a *real* number...yes, it is.

Comment: And it is also a rational number, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Mathematically, there is absolutely no difference, they are the same entity. But if you are a programmer, then you probably see it as a different type, because most computer languages deal with representations, not with abstract concepts that lie behind.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, precisely because $5 = 15 / 3$.

You should not mistake a representation of a number for the number itself. There are an infinite number of ways to represent the number $5$, but none of them changes the properties of the number $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Natural numbers are "one", "two", $\dots$. They are concepts. Usually one writes them as $1,2,\dots$. With respect to the set of rules stipulating what one can do with these numbers, we have 
$$
\frac{15}{3} = 5,
$$
say.
Hence $15/3$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you can *equate* it to a natural number, it is a natural number itself.

The equals sign "$=$" means that whatever is on the left side of it, is exactly the same as what is on the right side.

In the case of $$\frac{15}3 = 5$$ we have to recognize that whatever properties one side has, the other has also. So since 5 is a natural number, 15/3 must also be that, because they are **equal** to eachother.

Answer (score 1):

NATURAL NUMBERS are the subset of RATIONAL NUMBERS($\frac{p}{q}$).Therefore every natural number is rational number.

For x of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where p,q $\in Z$.
If
 $x\in Q$ need not implies $x\in N$ .

but for some $x\in Q$ ,If x is positive and q=1,then x is a natural number I.e 15/3=5/1 is a natural number.

Answer (score 0):

> All natural numbers are rational numbers because they can be represented $p/q$ and where q=1 .
>
> So , all rational number of form p/q ,where q=1 is natural number.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is voted down ,in my opinion your answer is nice.

Comment: I like this answer but you are forgetting to say yes, it is a natural number. Which may not be obvious to an OP with 31 rep.